# How to avoid redirection from Main application to gwt application when user clickes refresh/F5?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, url-rewriting

In my application, I included GWT module within iframe.

On click of button present in GWT module, I am assigning new url which is part of my application only, contents of new url coming within/same window.

```
Hyperlink eventStatusLink = new Hyperlink(moveToMainApplication, "");

    eventStatusLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            String eventStatusUrl = "/company/MainAppServlet?action=Launch&ID="+ IDFromGWT";
            // info("eventStatusUrl:"+eventStatusUrl);
            Window.Location.assign(eventStatusUrl);
        //Also called native method ::$wnd.location.href = url; not useful for me

        }
    });
```

I am able to redirect to my Main application but If user press F5/Refresh key on main application then page is redirected to my GWT application.

Window.Location.assign/replace not  replace the Main applications url in browser why?

Is there any way to do this using GWT ?

On my mainApplication User can press f5/refresh key

How to avoid redirection from my main application to gwt application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me :)

```
Hyperlink eventStatusLink = new Hyperlink(moveToMainApplication, "");

    eventStatusLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            String eventStatusUrl = "/company/MainAppServlet?action=Launch&ID="+ IDFromGWT";
            // info("eventStatusUrl:"+eventStatusUrl);
            //Window.Location.assign(eventStatusUrl);
          redirectToOtherModule(eventStatusUrl);

        }
    });
```

Native method is as follows:

```
 public static native String redirectToOtherModule(String url) /*-{
         return $wnd.redirectToOtherModule(url);
        }-*/;
```

//MyGWTModule.html

```
function redirectToOtherModule(url){
                window.top.location.href = url;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for ?

You can open the desired url in the same window  by using `Window.Open` and setting target as `_self`

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open(url, "_self",
           "param1=value," + 
           "param2=value");
}
```

Hope the above code will give you a hint .

And have a look on GWT [PlaceManager](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/customware/gwt/presenter/gwt-presenter/1.1.1/gwt-presenter-1.1.1-javadoc.jar!/net/customware/gwt/presenter/client/place/PlaceManager.html) also

Comment: @Suresh I already tired Window.open with _self . Not useful for my case